# Fazer um foreach dentro de um cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Está dando erro da forma que eu fiz o foreach. Se coloco @ dá erro no analisador. Se retiro dá outros erros. Como eu faço? Abaixo me código completo.

```
@model Ruptura.Models.RupturaEntities

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CadastroCargo";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutBase.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/Content/Jqwidgets/jqx.base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/Jqwidgets/jqx.summer.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<br />

<h3>Cadastro de Cargos</h3>

<br />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @*<div class="col-md-1">
                    <label for="txtCargo">Cargo:</label>
                </div>*@
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-6" name="txtCargo" id="txtCargo" placeholder="Digite um cargo válido">
            </div>
        </div>

        <br /><br />

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="text-center">Unidade de negócio</h3>';
            <div class="well" style="max-height: 350px;overflow: auto;">
                <ul class="list-group checked-list-box" id="check-list-box">

                    @{
                        foreach (var rpt in Model.Apresentacao)
                        {
                            <li class="list-group-item" data-style="button" data-color="success">rpt.Unidade_Negocio</li>
                        }
                    }

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <br /><br /><br />
            <div class="well" style="max-height: 300px;overflow: auto;">
                <ul class="list-group list-box">
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-style="button">Gerente Região Norte</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-style="button" data-color="success">Gerente Região Sul</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item" data-style="button" data-color="info">Gerente São Paulo</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="checkbox" for="ckbAtivo">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox large" data-label="suffix" data-label-prepend="prefix" name="ckbAtivo" id="ckbAtivo">Ativo
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

            <div id="content">
                <div class="listTree"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-success" onclick=" return GravaCargo();">Gravar</button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Voltar", "Index", "Home", new { }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="~/Scripts/CheckListBox/CheckListBox.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/CadastroCargo/CadastroCargo.js"></script>
```

Fiz isso e o erro continua:

```
@{
   if(Model.Apresentacao != null)
   { 
      foreach (var rpt in Model.Apresentacao){
      @:<li class="list-group-item" data-style="button" data-color="success">@rpt.Unidade_Negocio</li>
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: Tentou colocar apenas o `@foreach {...}` no lugar de abrir um bloco?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="well" style="max-height: 350px;overflow: auto;">
                <ul class="list-group checked-list-box" id="check-list-box">

                    @foreach (var rpt in Model.Apresentacao)
                        {
                            <li class="list-group-item" data-style="button" data-color="success">@rpt.Unidade_Negocio</li>
                        }
                    }

                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Dá esse erro: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_b0c3cso5.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: Necessito de instanciar quem, nesse caso.

Comment: nesse caso o Model.Apresentacao pode estar nulo, gerando erro de referencia, pode colocar um if verificando se ele nao está nulo a um nivel acima do foreach para garantir ( isso se é previsto que ele possa vir nulo)

Comment: Então, Apresentação é uma entidade do meu BD e eu tenho a plena certeza que ela está populada. O que posso fazer então para evitar isso? Digamos que vc tenha razão, mas eu digo que tenho dados. Então, como eu contorno isso, evitando esses erros de NullException sendo que há dados.

Comment: Então eu pergunto, o que levaria a Model ou a Model.Apresentacao estarem nulos? O que pode acontecer? Como disse, é uma entidade do BD que está populada. Então o que poderia acontecer?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim:

```
<ul class="list-group checked-list-box" id="check-list-box">

                    @{
                        Ruptura.Models.RupturaEntities db = new Ruptura.Models.RupturaEntities();
                        var result_ap = db.Apresentacao
                            .Select(a => new { a.Codigo_Unidade_Negocio, a.Unidade_Negocio }).ToList().Distinct();


                        foreach (var item in result_ap)
                        { 
                            <li class="list-group-item" data-style="button" data-color="success">@item.Unidade_Negocio</li>
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Marca essa como resposta certa, para fechar o tópico!